# DOM modification in mounted method not in JEST snapshot

Tags: d3.js, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I've got a Vue component and inside `mounted` method I have this:

```
this.el = d3.select(this.$el);
this.svg = this.el.select('svg')
        .attr('width', mainSvgPos.svgWidth)
        .attr('height', mainSvgPos.svgHeight)
        .attr('viewBox', "0 0 " + mainSvgPos.svgWidth + " " + mainSvgPos.svgHeight)
        .attr('style',"position:absolute;left:0;top:20px;width:100%;height:100%")   
this.chart = this.svg.select('g.chart').attr('transform', "translate(" + chartCenter.leftOffset + ", " + chartCenter.topOffset + ")")
```

I'm testing this component with `jest` and `vue-test-util`

My test looks like this:

```
describe('gauge', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(gauge, {
    propsData: ...some data,
  })
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.$el).toMatchSnapshot()
  });
})
```

When it runs for the first time, as expected, it creates the shapshot. In this snapshot, I have the parent `svg` element with all attributes set correctly (width, height, viewBox, style). However the `g.chart` element does not contain any attributes (it should contain `transform`). The mounted method creates a bunch of other elements using D3 syntax after that (I have not pasted them here)...none of that gets in the snapshot.

So my question is what happens in `this.svg = this.el.select('svg')...` that prevents the snapshot from being created properly and how do I fix that.

I've tried `nextTick`, `jest.useFakeTimers()`, `shallow` mounting, nothing gives me what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did several things to fix this:

1) No longer using `d3.select.attr` to modify  `svg` and `g.chart` attributes in mounted. I modified those attributes via props instead

2) In the original code, after this line:

```
this.chart = this.svg.select('g.chart').attr('transform', "translate(" + chartCenter.leftOffset + ", " + chartCenter.topOffset + ")")
```

I had a gradient arc generation via d3:

```
const arc = d3.arc()
          .innerRadius(this.arc_radius - this.chart_inset - this.bar_width)
          .outerRadius(this.arc_radius - this.chart_inset)
          .startAngle(function (d) {
            return d.startAngle;
          }).endAngle(function (d) {
            return d.endAngle;
          });

  d3.select(this.$el).append('g').selectAll('path').data(this.pieces).enter()
    .append('path').attr("d", arc)
    .attr("stroke-width", 1).attr("stroke", function (d) {
    return d.fill;
  }).attr("fill", function (d) {
    return d.fill;
  });
```

This also didn't get to the snapshot. Even after point 1 above was done. I moved this gradient arc generation into a new component's `mounted` method. And suddenly it started working. `shallow` on the new component created the markup correctly. Notice how in the new component, I still use `d3.selectAll`...but this time it works as expected

So this does not answer the previous issue but maybe refactoring the component's `mounted` method a bit will help.

Answer (score 1):

```
test('the d3 svg chart renders with the component', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(D3Chart, {
      attachToDocument: true,
    });
    expect(wrapper.html()).to.contain('svg');
    wrapper.destroy();
  });
```

As found in https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/369 helped me. I had to add
wrapper.destroy() at the end to remove the rendered elements from the document and destroy the component instance. https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachtodocument